# Computer Turned off during Ubuntu 14.04 Update

Tags: updates, 14.04, shutdown

My computer just turned off during an update from 12.04 to 14.04 it was in the middle of installing all the new software and packages. When I tried to turn it back on it would not boot up at all. Gave a black screen with a bunch of "command" lines (not sure what to call them). Have I lost everything on my hard drive? Is there a work around so that I can at least get back to the old version and try again?

Any help/links to help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is an update just continue with the update normally, you wont lose your files, if you have problems with recovering insert an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS USB and upgrade from there and you will have no problem. :)

Comment: Ok thanks so much, I'll give the USB option a try since it refuses to let me boot up.